# Is there a way to change the Date format inside SharePoint sites to be shown as DD MMM YY (i.e. 25 March 2017)

Tags: 2013, date-time, site-settings, sharepoint-farm, regional-settings

I am working on a sharepoint farm on-premises 2013. currently we set the following for the regional settings:-

[image]

Where all the date fields are being shown in this format `dd/mm/yyyy` for example something as follow `20/05/2017` either for the system generated date fields such as "Modified" & "Created" or for any site column of type date/time.
now i am not sure if i can change the date format to be shown as follow `20 May 2017` instead of `20/05/2017`?? Does the regional settings satisfy this ? so the month will be shown as character instead of as a number?

Answer (score -1):

you can use Calculated Column with below formula and choose Created/Modified column as Insert column:

```
=TEXT(EventDate,"dd mmm yy")
```

Comment: this will work on theory/paper,,, but in this case i will need to modify the built-in views and other components which show the date fields.. So creating calculated columns will require a huge amount of time/effort as i will need to modify all the built-in list forms (display,edit & create) to show the calculated columns... is this correct or i understand this approach wrongly.. while setting this on the regional settings (if possible) will just require changing the settings and having the effect all over the site...